In SwiftUI,should the NavigationView be inside the TabView or outside?Both have problems
When the NavigationView is placed outside the TabView, dismissing a sheet may cause an error view to be displayed.  (In SwiftUI, when the MyView popup sheet then dismissed, the MyView should be displayed instead of ListView).
On the other hand, if the NavigationView is placed inside the TabView, the TabView will remain at the bottom of the screen, even in child views where it's not needed. I need support iOS14,the .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar) modifier, which is available in later versions of iOS.

TabView should always be on top. HIG says that each tab should be murually exclusive from the others. Until that toolbar modifier was introduced there was no “right” way.

You need to switch to NavigationStack instead of NavigationView. Add a new NavigationStack for each tab item inside TabView. As such, each view of tab item will have its own NavigationStack.
